# Trello - Template Card with Text boxes is not inherited in the new cards

Tags: trello-cards

I created a Trello CARD template and as this being defect board, Modified the description text box with steps to reproduce, etc as text place holders and various other custom fields

But when I create a new card, I do not get the text created, I have to click on the template and edit it always.
1. As I inherit the custom fields, Is there a way to add text box in the Big description with header 1 and a few headers 2 like pre-conditions, Environment text boxes OR 
2. Is there a way I can make the template I created can be used with some settings, I may not be aware (I need help) to ensure each time I click on new card, I inherit all the data